# How to convert m3u to cue?

Tags: sed, tagging

EasyTag can save playlists in m3u only, but cue is required. How can sed convert?

It is required to glue all the lines with tags in the EXTINF block, rename EXTINF to TITLE, and move the line with the name of the mp3 file to the line above the TITLE.

It should be taken into account that the processed text may contain symbols CR and CR + LF. At least I failed to glue the paragraphs using sed '' s / $ // g '.

Good day

Comment: If you want a general solution perhaps it is better to look-up a converter online. Otherwise, we would need an example input and output to understand the question better.

Comment: I searched but did not find.

Comment: I'm trying to merge the lines into the sed:

sed 'H;g;s/\n//gp ; {:a;N;s/\(.*\)[\r\n$]{0,1}\(*\)/\2\1/g

not split :(

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that I'm answering a 3 yo. question but I came here via google and so may you.

A CUE file holds information from two sources: The CD TOC (timings) and the track titles and other metadata. A tagger, by its nature, can only deliver the track titles (a few may use an existing EAC log file though). The type of program you want to use to create CUE files is a CD ripper. All major tools in that category can create CUE files and will also lookup metadata for you.

If you don't have the CD or an CD image, your best bet is an online service like [cuenation.com](https://cuenation.com/?page=search) or the [CUETools Database (CTDB)](http://cue.tools/wiki/CUETools_Database). The latter is accessed via the [CUETools application](http://cue.tools/wiki/CUETools_Download) which unfortunately is only available for Windows and requires the .NET Framework. The outstanding feature of CUETools IMO is that it can compare your album copy against the CTDB online database and tell you whether your rip is accurate.

Comment: Timing here not only means the track lengths but also the gap lengths. While you can get the former just by reading information from the file header using tools like ffprobe or soxi, you need the CD TOC for the pregap index positions.

Answer (score -1):

The multi platform,open source music player Clementine, will open .cue files and play the long .mp3, .flac, or whatever. From there you can save the playlist as a .m3u file, without having to split the long file.

https://www.clementine-player.org/

Comment: The question was for the other way. m3u to cue.